# NetCore API Return pdf file in a POST request

Tags: c#, api, pdf, post, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using NET Core v2.0

I'm trying to accept a post request with an XML file as a Body, parse the request, and return a generated PDF file. Without going too deep into logic,
here's what I have in a controller :

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostMe() {
        return await Task.Run(async () => {
            try {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8)) {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlDocument));
                    var objectToParse = (XmlDocument) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    var pdfFileLocation = await _service.ParseObject(objectToParse);

                    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfFileLocation);

                    response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(file);
                    response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

                    return response;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        });
    }
```

XML file is a simple XML file I convert into an object, that part works and its irrelevant (also NDA).

I see couple (more than a couple) of questions similar to mine, but I've tried everything and didn't come up with a solution yet.
Using postman I get a response like so :

```
{
 "version": {
     "major": 1,
     "minor": 1,
     "build": -1,
     "revision": -1,
     "majorRevision": -1,
     "minorRevision": -1
 },
 "content": {
     "headers": [
         {
             "key": "Content-Type",
             "value": [
                 "application/pdf"
             ]
         }
     ]
 },
 "statusCode": 200,
 "reasonPhrase": "OK",
 "headers": [],
 "requestMessage": null,
 "isSuccessStatusCode": true 
}
```

As you can see, the `response.Content` acts as if nothing has been set. With 100% certainty, the file is created locally, and it's a valid pdf which I can open and see.

I've tried many variations of the response above, but nothing worked. It's either 406's, or empty content. Can anyone help me with this? I've been banging my head for past 4 hours.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, everything returned by a controller's action is serialized: you can't return an `HttpResponseMessage`, because that, too, will be serialized (this is what you see in your PostMan result).

Your method's signature should instead return `IActionResult`, and then you should call the [`File` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-3.1), like so:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> PostMe() {
    try {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8)) {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlDocument));
            var objectToParse = (XmlDocument) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            var pdfFileLocation = await _service.ParseObject(objectToParse);

            var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfFileLocation);

            // returns a variant of FileResult
            return File(file, "application/pdf", "my_file.pdf");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

Note that the `File` method return different variants of `FileResult`, depending on which overload you use.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that resolved my problem regarding the pdf. But now I cannot return IActionResult within the Task.Run(). Async Lambda expression converted to a 'Task' returning delegate cannot return a value. Did you intend to return 'Task<T>'. Which I'm pretty sure I am.

Comment: I forgot to remove the `Task.Run` construct. You don't need it, because you can directly mark your action as `async`.

Comment: Yes, I figured the change needed. Thanks a lot for the response!